# jQuery Show/Hide <div> for multiple unrelated sets of radio buttons within a single page

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on a long html form with different sets of radio buttons (yes/no, two options) with each set corresponding to separate hidden fields that appear depending on the selection.

My initial solution was to use jQuery's Show/Hide function to toggle the "hiddenfield" class's display: none; setting and to target divs containing the hidden fields by matching the value of the radio buttons to a second class. However, I'm not a jQuery expert by any means and my simple attempt can't differentiate between different sets of radio buttons. Instead only a single hiddenfield can be displayed at a time. So I'm looking for a more complete jQuery or javascript solution that will allow me to unhide a specific class (hiddenfield in my case) but only if the div also contains a class equal to the value of the radio button selected. All other hidden fields should stay in their respective hidden/shown states.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Here's my current code snippets:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        var targetHiddenfield = $("." + inputValue);
        $(".hiddenfield").not(targetHiddenfield).hide();
        $(targetHiddenfield).show();
    });
});
```

```css
.hiddenfield {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="cta__sub cta__sub--center">Do the members want to have meetings and formal voting processes or would they prefer to act with little formality.</p>
                <div class="double">
                  <p class="half">
                    <input name="formal_yesno" type="radio" id="radio9" value="formal_yes" />
                    <label for="radio9">Yes, formal meetings and voting.</label>
                  </p>
                  <p class="half">
                    <input name="formal_yesno" type="radio" id="radio10" value="formal_no" />
                    <label for="radio10">No, we will operate informally.</label>
                  </p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="formal_yes hiddenfield">
                <p class="cta__sub cta__sub--center">Will all members be entitled to notice and to have their voice heard, or will the minimum number for a majority decision be enough?</p>
                <div class="double">
                  <p class="half">
                    <input name="formal_y_extra" type="radio" id="radio11" value="formal_y_extra_yes" />
                    <label for="radio11">Yes, all members will be notified and heard.</label>
                  </p>
                  <p class="half">
                    <input name="formal_y_extra" type="radio" id="radio12" value="formal_y_extra_yes" />
                    <label for="radio12">No, only a majority is required.</label>
                  </p>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="formal_no hiddenfield">
                <p class="cta__sub cta__sub--center">Will some decisions require formal meetings and voting procedures?</p>
                <div class="double">
                  <p class="half">
                    <input name="formal_n_extra" type="radio" id="radio13" value="formal_n_extra_yes" />
                    <label for="radio13">Yes</label>
                  </p>
                  <p class="half">
                    <input name="formal_n_extra" type="radio" id="radio14" value="formal_n_extra_no" />
                    <label for="radio14">No</label>
                  </p>
                </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="formal_n_extra_yes hiddenfield">
                     <p class="cta__sub cta__sub--center">Please explain</p>
                    <textarea name='message' placeholder="Formal meetings and voting will occur...." id='textarea'></textarea>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in jQuery in `<script>` tag.

```
(.Role13).Click(function({
     (".Role9").show();
})
```

Comment: Since I don't know much about jQuery I'm not sure how to adjust your suggestion to my situation. To me it looks like I would have to copy that function for each set of radio buttons to keep them from interacting with others (if I'm wrong please let me know). Since there are more than a hundred sets and the longterm goal for the project requires the number of sets to change dynamically, I'm trying to figure out a universal solution in as few lines as possible to keep my file sizes from growing rapidly in the next stage of development.

Comment: Please briefly explain what you want to do.

Comment: I'm trying to build an html form. When certain radio buttons are selected, text boxes should appear to answer additional questions. There about 100 radio buttons with text boxes attached. My solution above works for one set of radio buttons at a time. When you select the next radio button the prior text box disappears. The data is still saved on submission, but it's difficult for the user to go back and edit their answers. I'm looking for a solution that allows all or any one of the radio boxes to be opened or closed regardless of any other radio buttons status.